# Occasional Exception when calling a method in wcf client proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Sometimes, on my xp machines, I get an exception when calling a method in my auto-generated client proxy. I told the debugger to stop on all clr exceptions.
Now sometimes when I call the following:

```
public MyStuff.Entities.Package GetPackageById(System.Guid sessionId, int packageId)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetPackageById(sessionId, packageId);
    }
```

I first get an InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified...
Pressing F10 results in a FileLoadException with the following messge:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=de-DE, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. **An operation is not legal in the current state.** (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131509)

I'm sure the service didn't throw an exception because it would show up as a FaultException. Since it's an **InvalidOperationException** that's being thrown when calling **base.Channel.GetPackageById(sessionId, packageId)** I assume it's not directly my fault?

I'm slowly running out of ideas what I could try to eliminate or work around this exception.

It never happened when using my developer machine with windows 7 and .NET 4.5 installed on it. On XP this will happen 1 out of 4 times approximately.

GetPackageById on service side looks like this:

```
public Package GetPackageById(Guid sessionId, int packageId)
        {
            try
            {
                return DataProvider.Provider.GetPackagesByKey(packageId,null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<MySericeFault>(new MySericeFault(ex));
            }                        
        }
```

The Package Class looks like this:

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [KnownType(typeof(MyApp.Entities.MachinePackage))]
    public partial class Package: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private DateTime? _outDate;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? OutDate
    {
        get { return _outDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_outDate != value)
            {
                _outDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OutDate");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _productId;
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductId
    {
        get { return _productId; }
        set
        {
            if (_productId != value)
            {
                _productId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductId");
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { _propertyChanged += value; } 
        remove { _propertyChanged -= value; }
    }
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds as though the WCF connection is being terminated abnormally and could be that the object being serialised is failing. Do you have code that shows object being serialised so we can check properties etc. Often circular references can cause this type of issue.

Comment: How do you close the connection to the service? And how is that handle when you get the first exception? I think you need to post mode code get get a dead on answer!

Comment: As written in the first sentence it is auto-generated with svcutil (.NET 4)

Comment: Could you post the content of the `GetPackageById` method?

Comment: @Jocke: I close it like suggested by microsoft: try{...client.close}catch{client.abort}

Comment: Maybe you didn't see my edited comment but could you please provide the class Package including [DataContract] attributes etc.

Comment: Is there any `foreach` loop in the `GetPackagesByKey` method?

Comment: Maybe you can enable tracing in the service web.config and then use `svctraceviewer.exe` to see the trace. This way you can see transport errors, etc., which happen in the WCF infrastructure, which you can't debug yourself.

Comment: On the client side trace there is an unhandled exception (IOE) like I posted before. On service side there seems to be a CommunicationObjectAbortedException.

Comment: You are not hooking into the PropertyChanged event on the server before sending back are you?

Comment: Nope. The change tracking is for the wpf client.

Comment: @StevenS., how about an answer to my question above?

Comment: @Alex: There is no foreach loop in the method. If there was, I would have some exception handling there anyway.

Comment: Is there an easy alternative to the auto-generated proxy?

Comment: _Collection was modified_ makes me believe that somehow a `Package` collection is being modified during the looping (hence my `foreach` question). The fact that you experience the problem only on one machine could be caused by the different collection parsing time on the 2 machines. Are they using the same repository for the entities? Is the collection a fast-changing collection?

Comment: My 2 WinXP machines and about 50 more at the customer sites show this behavior. I'm pretty sure it's not happening in the code that I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an experiment but too big to put as a comment!

Try creating a new operation contract that performs this code:

**Service:**

```
public Package GetPackageByIdTest(Guid sessionId, int packageId)
{
    return new Package { ProductId = packageId, OutDate = DateTime.Now };
}
```

Then create a console application that references your service and write something like this:

**Client:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int tester = 0; tester < 2000; tester++)
    {
        using (var service = new ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
        {
            Package result = service.GetPackageByIdTest(Guid.NewGuid(), tester);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ProductId);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    return;
}
```

Then, try running that on one of the known XP machines that fails and see if you get the same issue. If not it would suggest there is something going a miss in your `DataProvider.Provider.GetPackagesByKey(...)` method.

Comment: I am deliberately closing and re-opening the service to try and trip it up but I think it will work ok as I suspect the real issue is in the provider.

Comment: I used this to test my service calls and it turned out that my service is pretty robust. I ended up delaying some calls from the client at the start and now it works like a charm. I guess I'll have to leave it like this until Windows XP is really gone! Would it be legitimate to accept this as an answer, even though it doesn't really answer the question I initially asked?

Comment: That really is down to you. If it helped lead you to the answer / solution I'd say yes but there are no hard / fast rules.